# Create entries in /sys filesystem

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I'm trying to add some files in /sys/devices/platform to test my program but looks like the sysfs is not editable. Is there a way I can add/fake a /sys entry?

Comment: Short answer: No.  If the driver isn't making the correct entries; there's something wrong with the driver.  Q: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Perhaps there's another, different solution to your underlying problem?

Comment: Create your own `sysfs` driver?

Comment: How about using /proc or /debugfs instead?

Comment: @paulsm4 I don't have the source code for the program but it basically checks for slaves on i2c buses. What I did end up doing was settings SYSFS_PATH environment variable (from which the program apparently read) to a fake sys directory and this worked out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use a linux kernel module if you want to actually add files there, but I would advise against this for testing a program.

`chroot` could be used to make a fake filesystem to run your code in, but this is probably excessively complicated.

I'd suggest using a `SYS_PATH` value, so you could recompile your program for testing and have it look elsewhere.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define SYS_PATH "/home/user/myfakesys"
#else
#define SYS_PATH "/sys"
#endif
```

...

```
FILE *f = fopen(SYS_PATH "/devices/platform/...", "wb");
```

Comment: Thank you! I dont have the source code for it but it apparently reads from SYSFS_PATH environment variable, which I was able to set to a fake sys directory. :D